# UIButton AddTarget in ios(not working-crashing)

Tags: objective-c, ios, unity-game-engine

I have created UIButton programatically , which is added to UIViewController which is also created programtically. I donot know what to pass as AddTarget.

I have currently passed optionView.self in addtarget

```
 UIWindow *window1 = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
   optionView  = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
   optionView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 960, 640);
   UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);
   [button setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button addTarget:optionView.self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [optionView.view addSubview:button];
   [window1 addSubview: optionView.view];
```

And also this is my selector method

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"This works");

}
```

And also i am getting following error

unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fd7b600'

Please not that i am using Unity3d Game Engine. This code is in (Unity3d it is in APPController.mm)

Comment: Is setting the target crashing or pressing the button?

Comment: @Alexander it is crashing when i click the button

Comment: @Alexander But crash is prevented when i set addtarget to nil. But then the selector doesnot get called

Comment: Where have you written your selector method

Comment: In the same file AppController.mm where i have written the above code posted in the question

Comment: Found the solution did as @leo_fender suggested. Thank you all for helping me with quickly. Love stackoverflow community. Also everyone using Unity3d as gameengine and wanted to add UIButton in your main window using xcode do as he has suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewController `optionView` does not have buttonClicked selector, that's why app crashes.

If you want, you can create child class from ViewController, implement your method there and create optionView as instance of your new class. Then it will respond to call.

Or another way - you can extend base ViewController class by creating category for it with `buttonClicked` selector.

Comment: Thousands thanks to you . Finally got it working using your way

Answer (score 1):

If you have `buttonClicked:` method in the same class you are setting the target, it should be `self` instead of `optionView.self`.

Comment: i donot have access to the self. As i am using Unity3d Game Engine.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to create this button in the **optionView** , not in app delegate , app is crashing because it is going to find buttonClicked method in optionView and there is not any method in 
optionView yet.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);
[button setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.window addSubview: button];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: optionView is added in UIViewController. UIViewController is also created programatically then added to the window. As shown in my code

Comment: try,[button addTarget:optionView action:@selector(buttonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: or just button in your mainwindow , and set [button addTarget: window1 action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; ,no need to add viewcontroller for this.

Comment: tried both the solutions beforehand but they both give the same crash

Comment: It would work fine in APPDelegate.mm but would in APPController.mm that i have for unity3d game

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the target should be changed to `optionView` instead of `optionView.self`

Comment: Would not work as i donot have access to self. As i am using Unity3d Game Engine